Agreement with "si" as an impersonal pronoun
When I used DeepL to translate the phrase "There is so much english media around so when you were growing up, you were naturally exposed to all of that" and it returned "Ci sono così tanti media inglesi in giro che quando si cresceva si era esposti a tutto questo in modo naturale".
The question I have is why did DeepL here use "si era esposti" and not "si era esposto". Isn't "si" here just the third-person singular pronoun, which is why it says "si cresceva" and not "si crescevano"? I have a feeling esposti is somehow agreeing with i media but it doesn't make any sense to me because it's describing "si". Thanks for any clarification!

This is a very complicated question -- the rules for agreement with the si construction are rather arcane in Italian. I wrote an old answer about them. I will see if I have time to write a more specific answer here as well.. (btw this has nothing to do with "media": the verb would be in the plural even if the sentence started with "quando").

«the third-person singular pronoun»: This is unfortunately wrong. As @DenisNardin says, si is a complicated word, which can be use in reflexive constructions (“i ragazzi si lavano”) and impersonal ones (“qui si mangia bene”) as well as in the so called passivante ones (“qui si mangiano buone specialità”). And, as you may already see in some of these examples, si is not especially singular.

That said, the translation by DeepL is not especially idiomatic. I'd avoid to impersonal construction with si so close to each other, and something in the word order sounds wooden.

@DaG to soothe my worries a little, would it still sound ok if I did not conjugate si right in this context? Is this one of those grammatical rules that you might be taught in school (like no prepositions at the end of a sentence for english) but in casual conversation it's neither here nor there?

@PenandPaper Unfortunately it's the exact opposite - the rule is not taught in school (because it's a mess) but if you don't do it right you will be understood but sound very weird. Still, it's not a very common construction so you shouldn't be too worried about it.

@PenandPaper I agree with Denis Nardin: it's not a matter of school grammar, but rather of actual spoken Italian.
